# Should I use cookies or local storage to persist data to the front end?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to persist data to the front end so that I don't have to make a request to the back end every time that a user switches pages. I want to display the user data, minus sensitive things such as email and passwords and things of that nature. I've researched a bit about local storage and cookies, and I'm already using local storage to store a JWT that keeps the user logged in for an hour, as well as a username that I use to make a call to the back end to get that users information. But I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this the right way.

Should I be persisting data using local storage on the front end so that I can display it for pages such as user profile? If not, how should I persist data so that I don't have to make a ton of calls to the back end? Should that be cookies? Should I just continue to make calls to the backend?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. I will provide you some degrees on persisting data vs calling to the backend. And you decide what to store locally.

### security

persisting data locally is not safe, i don't think you should store sensitive things locally. As for other unimportant things, it's ok.

### timeliness

data updated frequently and time-efficiently is not appropriate to store locally.

By the way, i think you should request users information via JWT rather than username. username is always valid and JWT will expire in an hour. And save user password nowhere except your database, use an time-limited token instead for auto login.

Comment: So should i be saving the JWT to my db? That seems like an good idea, thanks for the input.

Comment: @Branduo i think it a good idea to saving JWT into a redis db. it is native support time-based feature.